# Attribute extraction from itext.layout.element in c#

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

Currently, I am working on a project to generate a Table of Content for pdf using itext What I have is a list of elements (itext.layout.Element objects).

I have created a dictionary< string, int> where we store (chapter title and start page number). I want to consider

`<p class="Heading2ANOC" >`  paragraphs whose Class  is Heading2ANOC are chapters title

Mycode :

```
var toc = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach (IElement element in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.GetType().Name);
    if (element.GetType().Name == "HtmlPageBreak")
    {
        continue;
    }

    else if (element.GetType().Name == "Paragraph")//need a method to check wheather the class is "Heading2ANOC" {

        int count=pdf.GetNumberOfPages();
        toc.Add("section" + i, count);// 
        i++;

    }
   document.Add((IBlockElement)element);
}
```

I am getting Elements by using follwing code :

```
string path = "path for the Html";
string html = File.ReadAllText(path);
IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html);
```

example Html element:

```
<div style="mso-element: para-border-div; border: solid #A6A6A6 2.25pt; padding: 3.0pt 4.0pt 3.0pt 4.0pt; background: #D9D9D9;">
<p class="Heading2ANOC"><span style="mso-bookmark: _Toc190800487;"><span style="mso-bookmark: _Toc377720650;"><span style="mso-bookmark: _Toc396995390;"><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif; color: black; mso-color-alt: windowtext;">SECTION 1 <span style="mso-tab-count: 1;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Name of the section</span></span></span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, you are probably using `HtmlConverter`, right? Could you attach the code including the invocation of `HtmlConverter`?

Comment: yes I am using  ```HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cleaner (and more flexible) way to approach the task compared to the approach you are taking now, but it requires writing more code. Fortunately, the code is pretty basic.

To understand what needs to be customized, you need to understand how pdfHTML works a bit. Roughly speaking, it traverses the DOM tree in DFS order and converts the DOM tree into the element tree. Each tag is traversed by a tag worker and that tag worker produces an element as a result. The elements are flexible enough to contain any custom properties (as long as you use a unique property ID not used by iText), so you can set those properties in tag workers and use them later on. In this case you want to pass along `class` property/attribute.

First off, let's create a custom tag worker deriving from `PTagWorker` that will process all the paragraphs in the HTML and set a custom property:

```
public static readonly int CUSTOM_PROPERTY_ID = -10;

private class CustomPTagWorker : PTagWorker {
    public CustomPTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) : base(element, context) {
    }

    public override void ProcessEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        base.ProcessEnd(element, context);
        IPropertyContainer elementResult = GetElementResult();
        if (elementResult != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(element.GetAttribute(AttributeConstants.CLASS))) {
            elementResult.SetProperty(CUSTOM_PROPERTY_ID, element.GetAttribute(AttributeConstants.CLASS));
        }
    }
}
```

Then we need to use that tag worker somehow - for that we create a custom tag worker factory:

```
private class CustomTagWorkerFactory : DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    public override ITagWorker GetCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (TagConstants.P.Equals(tag.Name().ToLower())) {
            return new CustomPTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return base.GetCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}
```

All we need to do now is make pdfHTML aware of those customizations by passing the custom tag worker in the converter properties:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().SetTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
```

To test it out, we can iterate over the elements and check for the presence of our custom property (instead of checking for names of the classes):

```
String html = "<p class=\"Heading2ANOC\">hello</p><p>world</p>";
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().SetTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html, properties);
foreach (IElement element in elements)
{
    if (element.HasProperty(CUSTOM_PROPERTY_ID)) {
        String propertyValue = element.GetProperty<String>(CUSTOM_PROPERTY_ID);
        Console.WriteLine(propertyValue);
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that for more complicated HTMLs where elements nest into each other you might want to perform the final analysis in a different way, e.g.

```
foreach (IElement element in elements)
{
    if (element is AbstractElement<Div>) {
        var children = (element as AbstractElement<Div>).GetChildren();
        // analyze children
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying one more variant <p><span class="new"></span> </p>  I have created CustomSpanTag to read the class property as above the problem is ```IPropertyContainer elementResult = GetElementResult();``` always returning NULL instead of the element

Comment: @NithinAnchuri you can use `getAllElements` for `SpanTagWorker`